# Why doesn't file picker on macOS show recent photos taken on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, finder, photos, photo-stream

Super simple use case:

1. Take a picture on iPhone.
2. Go to Mac, open a program where I can choose a file to send to a friend.
3. Click on Media / Photos in the shortcuts bar.
4. Wait for it ... intended picture DOES NOT appear.  Instead, I see bunch of old pictures.

Why doesn't Finder's Photos integration not able to show the latest pictures I took on my iPhone?

Isn't the whole idea of this that I can see what is in my Photos library?

And, I have verified that the intended picture is actually showing up in Photos app, just not in the file picker in the Finder integration.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the Mac?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the files are not downloaded to the Mac but exist only on iCloud.  Once you download them within Photos then they should appear in the Finder media picker.
I hate this, I can't figure out why it has to be so bad.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).